# GNU Screen switch to different window

Tags: gnu-screen

I have these in my `.screenrc` file:

```
screen -t ghci 0
screen -t bash 1
screen -t dev 4
```

Now, I put these in my my `.screenrc` file to split them:

```
split -v
focus
```

Now I want to switch to the window `bash` on the split screen. Right now that window is empty. How do I do that? I don't want to do that interactively. Is there any command which I can place in `.screenrc` which will achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page for screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Selecting) has `select`, `prev` and `next` for window selection.